# How can I set different color for my tab label independent of background color?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

How can I set Separate color for my tab label? If I change the background color whole color changes.

my code

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

 </FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res/drawable/tabselector.xml`

```
<selector
android:id="@+id/myselector"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/darklogo" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/lightlogo" />
</selector>
```

The XML you've included here is a way of defining a drawable that lets you embed a case statement. It presents a different drawable depending on the state of the View it's being assigned to. As a drawable, you should save it as an xml file within the `res/drawable` folder of your project (for example `tabselector.xml`).

To use it for the Tabhost, you need to construct the TabActivity as you normally would (as shown in this [tutorial example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)).

Then when you add each tab to the host, you specify the `tabselector` drawable as the indicator as shown for "TAB 1" below.

```
Drawable mySelector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselector);

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1", mySelector).setContent(R.id.textview1));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.textview2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do such a thing by following this

```
String TAG_AddData="TAB LABEL";
        /*add Tab in Tabgroup*/
        TabHost host = getTabHost();
                host.addTab(host
                        .newTabSpec(TAG_AddData)
                        .setIndicator(TAG_AddData,
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_add))
                        .setContent(
                                new Intent(this, AddData_ActivityGroups.class)
                                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
```

/* Now you can loop through all the tabs ang chnage its label properties*/

```
    for (int i = 0; i < host.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

    TextView tv = (TextView) host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) host.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(
    android.R.id.title); // for Selected Tab
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

And same thing you can apply in onTabChanged Method of **tabGroup**